# How to paint only DataGridView's cell background not its content?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i need to paint only background of DataGridView cell not its Content.But  while i'm doing painting it paint its content too.Please help me out.

My code goes like this.

```
private void Daywisegrid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == 0 )

            {
                using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.Daywisegrid.GridColor))
                {
                    using (Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
                    {
                        using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
                        {
                            // Clear cell 
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                            //Bottom line drawing
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1 , e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1);


                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i am not sure why you need to catch CellPainting event to change cell background color just do it like this

```
Daywisegrid.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

But if you want to do it in painting try this

```
private void Daywisegrid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == 0 )

            {
                using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.Daywisegrid.GridColor))
                {
                    using (Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
                    {
                        using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
                        {
                            // Clear cell 
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                            //Bottom line drawing
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1 , e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1);

                              // here you force paint of content
                             e.PaintContent( e.ClipBounds  );
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1 , e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
```

`e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1` point would be erased by next cell.