# Is it possible to fill only half a cell background color GridView at C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I a GridView table that filed with data.. and I would like for some reason to fill the background color of each cell.. But here is the catch.. I need to fill only 1/10 of the cell size with the color. Is it possible to do this? If it does - how?
I'm using winforms with c#.

Thanks a-lot.

Comment: any screen shot simply depicting what you want? we can fill it at any position with just simple info you provided `1/10`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this solution (tested)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex < 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            //Watch out for the Index of Rows (here 0 for testing)
            string text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

            // Clear cell 
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width / 10 , e.CellBounds.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top + 2));
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Silver), new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width - 1, e.CellBounds.Height - 1));
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use [CellPainting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) event, but you literally must draw cell on your own. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

[How to paint only DataGridView's cell background not its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041044/how-to-paint-only-datagridviews-cell-background-not-its-content)

In the step:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
```

define your own bounds for the rectangle, instead of using those of the cell..