# How do I conditionally change a datagridview's cell format in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Form Load event I have a List of objects that I add to a BindingSource.  The very last line of code I call in my load event is:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

I have tried to change the cell formatting using a dataGridView1_CellPainting event as well as a dataGridView1_CellFormatting event.  Neither event gets called.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Sorry.  Change the background color.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041044/how-to-paint-only-datagridviews-cell-background-not-its-content

Comment: It seems as if my CellPainting event is not being raised.

Comment: Did you subscribe to it, either in design or code?

Comment: I thought I did Don.  Wow  I knew it was something simple.  I should delete this question, don't you think ?

Comment: It's still probably useful for someone...you aren't the first to do it, and you won't be the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive the `CellPainting` event from the grid you must subscribe to it.  This can be done in the form designer, or in code.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that you can handle changing the color and other cell styling features through the use of the `DefaultCellStyle` property. This can be applied at the grid level, row level, column level, all the way down to the individual cell level. Here is a nice image showing how the styling is inherited:

[image: CellStyle inheritance]

If possible, it's best to apply a style at the highest level of the hierarchy and let it be inherited to the cells. This is the same reason you want to avoid using the `CellPainting` and `CellFormatting` events to color the cells; You're processing the event for every cell, and it can be done much more efficiently. You might not notice it for small data sets or simple grids, but it will slow you down if you need to scale. Use those events when you need to apply a custom formatting or aspect of how a cell is drawn, but for coloring you can be more efficient. See [Best Practices Cell Styling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

From the information given, it appears you're trying to apply a cell color to the auto generated columns of your grid post data binding. My suggestion to you would be to style your DataGrid in the `DataBindingComplete` event using the above mentioned techniques. You can apply your conditional styling there with the latest bound data, and avoid over processing in `CellPainting`.